# How to replace punctuation with whitespace

Tags: python

```
punc_list = [".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","'","\""]
new_s = ''
for i in s:
    if i not in punc_list:
        new_s += i
return new_s.lower()
```

If the input is

```
s = ("Hey! M'y nam;e i's")
```

I would want the output to be:

```
s = ('hey  m y name e i s')
```

I am having trouble replacing punc with whitespace

Comment: Is this homework, or can you use regular expressions? Also, just _exactly those_ punctuation, or _all_ special characters?

Comment: In the `else` branch, add a white space.

Comment: @tobias_k yes it's homework. I'm considering all special characters

Comment: @DYZ ohh okay it works! thank you!

Comment: Forgot square brackets `[]`?

Comment: As a side note, I suggest that you use `string.punctuation` instead of your own `punct_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @DYZ said, you just need another conditional statement that replaces the special characters with spaces:

```
def func(s):
    punc_list = [".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","'","\""]
    new_s = ''
    for i in s:
        if i not in punc_list:
            new_s += i
        else:
            new_s += ' '
    return new_s.lower()

s = ("Hey! M'y nam;e i's")
new_s = func(s)
print (new_s)
```

Output would look like what you wanted: `hey  m y nam e i s`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add a space `' '` when the character is punctuation. Also, `punc_list` does not actually have to be a `list`; you can just make it one long string and iterate the characters, or as noted in comments, just use `string.punctuation`. And to improve lookup speed, you could also make it a `set`, but it really should not matter much in this case:

```
punc_list = set('.;:!?/\\,#@$&)(\'"')  # or use string.punctuation

def no_punc(s):
    new_s = ''
    for i in s:
        if i not in punc_list:
            new_s += i
        else:
            new_s += ' '
    return new_s.lower()
```

Or a bit shorter, using a ternary expression [`... if ... else ...`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
def no_punc(s):
    new_s = ''
    for i in s:
        new_s += i if i not in punc_list else ' '
    return new_s.lower()
```

Or even shorter, using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def no_punc(s):
    return ''.join(i if i not in punc_list else ' ' for i in s).lower()
```

Or *even* shorter, using regular expressions [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html):

```
import re
def no_punc(s):
    return re.sub("\W", " ", s).lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.translate`. To convert all the characters in the `punc_list` to spaces.

```
>>> punc_list = [".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","'","\""]
>>> s = "Hey! M'y nam;e i's"
>>> s.translate({ord(p): " " for p in punc_list})
'Hey  M y nam e i s'
```

You can create a dictionary mapping on the fly using a dict comprehension, which maps all the punctuation character codes (uses `ord` function) to a space.

Comment: Why not just  `{ord(x): ' ' for x in punc_list}`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the homework question supposed to help you learn about loops? Learning about dicts and translate is useful too i think.

```
t = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(punc_list, " "))
new_s = s.lower().translate(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Works on Python 3.8.2

```
import string 

punc_list = '.;:!?/\,#@$&)(\'"'
replacement =  ' '*len(punc_list)

def func(s):
    new_s = s.translate(str.maketrans(punc_list, replacement))
    return new_s

print(func("Hey! M'y nam;e i's"))
```

Comment: Please add an explenation to the code so the person who asked can understand why you gave this solution and why its working.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add an else statement to `if i not in punc_list:` so that the code looks like this:

```
punc_list = [".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","'","\""]
new_s = ''
for i in s:
    if i not in punc_list:
        new_s += i
    else:
        new_s += ' '

return new_s.lower()
```

All this does is say:
If the character isn't in the punctuation list add it to the new `string`.
If it is in the punctuation list add a whitespace to the new `string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

See this code , with using 2 loops :

```
punc_list = [".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","'","\""]
s = "Hey! M'y nam;e i's"
new_s = ''

for x in punc_list:
  for i in s:
    if i==x:
        s=s.replace(i,new_s)


print(s)
```